# Visual studio 2013 web form and design view equivalent in Visual studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm following an ASP.NET course series where the instructor uses Visual Studio 2013, and I can't figure out what the equivalent is in 2019 for the settings he uses. He creates a new ASP.NET Web Application, then picks the Empty template, but there are additional options that I can't see when creating mine, specifically the web forms box.

Web form (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy2x3.png)

I tried to do the same, but when he continues he is able to "Add a web form" to the project. He creates a web form with the .aspx extension.

Web form (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W9te.png)

He is also able to enter a design view mode, which I can't see. I can right click html or htmlcs files and open them with a web forms editor option, but at that point all the HTML items in my toolbox disappear(pointer, button, textarea, input, etc.). I tried to pick the ASP.NET Web application template as well but it didn't make a difference with my issue.

Design mode (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYYYF.png)

Or would it be better to just use VS 2013 for this course?

Comment: Do you really need to learn WebForms for some specific reason? It's more or less legacy tech now. If you're just starting out with ASP.NET I'd advise a) learning ASP.NET Core rather than ASP.NET, and b) learning MVC or Razor pages instead of WebForms. That'll give you a much more up to date, relevant and future-proofed set of skills. The fact the course you're following is using a 5-year-old version of Visual Studio (which has been superseded three times already) should be a warning flag that this isn't the latest and greatest...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: No I suppose WebForms isn't really what I need to learn. The course is called "C# fundamentals via ASP.NET web applications", so I guess what I'm actually trying to learn is C# fundamentals.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/get-started?tabs=windows might be more what you need then. If you're just learning C# the language, then I really wouldn't complicate that with all the bells and whistles of a web application as well (unless you're already very familiar with developing web applications in other languages). Just start with simple console apps instead

Comment: Can you contact the instructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET Web Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Forms) is an old technology:

> Web Forms was included in the original .NET Framework 1.0 release in 2002, as the first programming model available in ASP.NET. Unlike newer ASP.NET components, Web Forms is not supported by ASP.NET Core.

If you navigate to the [ASP.Net Web Forms page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-forms), Microsoft tells you this:

> **Consider Razor Pages instead of Web Forms**
>   Razor Pages is a more modern alternative for building web apps using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and C#. Razor Pages can run on .NET Core - a high performance, cross-platform and open-source version of .NET that runs on Linux, macOS, and Windows.

If you *must* learn ASP.NET Web Forms, it *is* supported in Visual Studio 2019:
[image: Web Forms in Visual Studio 2019]

Comment: "it _is_ supported in Visual Studio 2019"... provided you have installed the "ASP.NET and web development" workload

Comment: Unfortunately this answer reads like the jocular "I wouldn't start from here" when someone stops by the side of the road to ask for directions.  Also, since we're talking about an "absolute beginner" answer here it would be helpful to explain what buttons someone needs to press from an "empty template" project to get to the screen snippet you show at "If you must learn...".

Answer (score 1):

OP is requesting comparison between the "New Project" gui wizard steps, for Visual Studio 2019 (vs-2019) to pre-2019 versions. The request also has a student learning context.

Please find an example doing that for the task of creating a "Web Forms with Master" application with vs-2019 mapped to vs-2015, using: 
Murach's ASP.NET 4.6 with C# 2015, 
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, 
Visual Studio 16.4.3

The vs-2015 version has an option for the user to create a web forms with master application. The button "Web Form with Master" is routinely illustrated in books and online tutorials, walking learners through step-by-step to reach an intended result. That button is gone, the feature is not gone.

The web form with master option in vs-2019 is called "Web API" and can be enabled on the "Create New Web Application" wizard/gui screen.

[image: Murach's ASP.NET 4.6 with C# 2015] "Web Web Form with Master Page" button has become [image: WEB API checkbox] in vs-2019.

---

Mapping Steps

See illustrations to create a Master Page ASP.NET application in vs-2019. How to enable Web API and Site.Master

With vs-2019 running, a user activates the new project gui/wizard with the following toolbar selections: File -> New -> Project... [image: see image]

Wizard/GUI vs-2019

Create a New Project in ~ image 3 missing ~ next ~ ASP.NET Web Application (DOT.NET) ~ [image: see image] ~ next ~ Configure your new project ~~ (i.e., name it, and set file system path) ~ [image: see image] ~ next ~ Create a new ASP.NET Web Application ~ Web Forms ~~ Add folders & core references ~~ [ Checkbox ] Web API [image: see image]

The resulting [image: vs-2019 application]
The resulting [image: vs-2015 application]

add dots to see missing image three: i stack imgur com/FpKBb png